# How do I add a class name or data-* to widgetof "nex/yii2-chosen"

Tags: php, yii2, jquery-chosen

i am using "nex/yii2-chosen" 
and how can we add 'class' attribute or 'data-*' in below example

```
<?=
$form->field($model, "vehicle_id")->widget(Chosen::className(), [
    'items' => $VehicleList,
    'disableSearch' => 5,
    'class' => 'vehicle_id form-control input-sm',    <---------------not working
    'clientOptions' => [
        'search_contains' => true,
        'single_backstroke_delete' => false,
    ]
]) ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to put them in `options` property.

```php
<?=
$form->field($model, "vehicle_id")->widget(Chosen::className(), [
    'items' => $VehicleList,
    'disableSearch' => 5,
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'vehicle_id form-control input-sm',
    ],
    'clientOptions' => [
        'search_contains' => true,
        'single_backstroke_delete' => false,
    ]
]) ?>
```